# grep: colorize only first match in each line

Tags: grep

```
INPUT | grep --color=always "$string\{1,1\}"
```

... alas, every instance of $string is highlighted.  As I read the docs, the '{1,1}' should insure that only the first instance is highlighted.  Or is there a better tool?  I can't use sed

```
INPUT | sed -r "s|$string|${red}$string${nrm}|I"
```

( ${red} and ${nrm} are just color codes )

because the INPUT here is a list of files which might be found case insensitively and if I use the 'I' option with sed, it forces the case of the file list to change to the exact text of the input to the command -- that is, I want to search for files without case, but highlight insensitively whatever the case of the string within the file list might happen to be.

```
my_command *file_name*
```

... will use 'find' to look for the files case insensitively but in the listing I want to highlight:

```
file_name 
FILE_nAME 
file_NAME_this_file_has_a_long_file_name
```

... but only the first instance (a filename might contain repetitions of the input string). So in the last line above 'file_NAME' is highlighted, but 'file_name' is not.

grep has no problem with the case issue but sed does.  OTOH, sed knows how to stop after one match and grep seems not to. Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you *can* use `sed` if you use pattern substitution (the match is case insensitive, but the replacement uses the captured pattern, not the searched one):

```
INPUT | sed -r "s|(${string})|${red}\\1${nrm}|I"
```

Also, as @don_crissti noticed, if you want to colorize the *entire* found pattern, you needn't even use a capture group, you can use the "whatever it was" `&` code which is probably also slightly faster:

```
INPUT | sed -r "s|${string}|${red}&${nrm}|I"
```

Using two strings instead of color codes it seems to work on my bash:

```
$ red="_RED_"
$ nrm="_NORM_"
$ string="amd"
$ echo -e "linux-5.4.0-amd-backfire.tar.bz2\\nThis is AMD Radeon\\nNames: Amdiranifani amd Jefri" \
  | sed -r "s|(${string})|${red}\\1${nrm}|I"

linux-5.4.0-_RED_amd_NORM_-backfire.tar.bz2
This is _RED_AMD_NORM_ Radeon
Names: _RED_Amd_NORM_iranifani amd Jefri
```

The second "amd" in the third line does not get replaced, and all other replacements keep their original case.

The `grep` syntax means that it will match the first *continuous repetition* of a pattern, so in "bababa" will match only the first "ba", but in "baba___ba" it will match the first and the third occurrence.

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44222946/make-grep-colour-only-capture-groups) grep colors the *whole* match, so can't be used in this instance.

Comment: Bullseye!  One question: why the double backslash: '\\1'?  I used your sample above including my color variables but it seems fine with a single backslash.

Comment: You actually don't need a capture group `()` and `\\1` in this particular case, just use `${string}` in the LHS and `&` in the RHS. For people who don't have access to gnu sed and its `I` flag: use `[sS][tT][rR][iI][nN][gG]` (the actual value not the var name) in the LHS.

Comment: @RayAndrews the backslash is the escape character, so I need to escape it *twice* in strings. You're right that it will work anyway, because the parser is clever enough to surmise that "\1" is not an escape code since 1 needs no escaping, so `echo "\1"` and `echo "\\1"` yield the same result. But `echo "\\n"` and `echo "\n"` do not.

I routinely make mistakes when entering backslashes :-D

Comment: @don_crissti True! Added to the answer, thanks.

Comment: Ah!  I didn't understand Don's comment but now I do, thanks both.

Answer (score 2):

If your `grep` support `-P` for perl-like regexps, you could do:

```
grep --color=always -P "^.*?\K\Q$string\E"
```

That can only match once per line since we're using `^` to anchor the match at the start of the line. That's followed by `.*?` that matches any number of characters *as few as possible*, and `$string` within `\Q`/`\E` so the contents of the `$string` variable is matched literally even it happens to contain regexp operators (other than `\E`). `\K` specifies that only what follows is to be `K`ept, so here coloured.

Or you could use the real thing and not have to rely on any GNUism:

```
STRING=$string perl -ne 'print if s/\Q$ENV{STRING}\E/\e[31m$&\e[m/'
```

Which works even if `$string` contains `\E`.

Comment: More and more I'm beginning to think I'd better learn perl. I solved one problem simply by replacing sed with perl and I didn't even have to change the command tail at all -- perl was a drop-in replacement.